# Meteor collection query with current timestamp

Tags: date, collections, find, meteor

I need to schedule items which have an attribute 'scheduledAt with timestamps, both current and projected. Unfortunately the reference Date is only calculated once.

How can this be solved?

```
Items.find({scheduledAt : {$lt : new Date()}}).observe(...)
```

Comment: Passing "new Date()" will pass the toString() of the date object, which probably isn't what you want. Try passing "+new Date()" to cast it to the actual timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Because Meteor is a single page app, "new Date()" is not going to get called unless you make it reactive by doing something like:

function findItems() {
    Session.get
    Items.find({scheduledAt : {$lt : new Date()}}).observe(...)
}

And you can trigger by doing
Session.set('triggerEvent');

If you just want to do it periodically, use Meteor.setTimeout()